How to match lines starting with an upper case letter and have 1 to 10 words per line using regular expressions
I am trying to build an efficient regular regression that joins multiple lines with the following constraints to a single line.

The first lines start with an upper case letter and end with a colon character.
Other consecutive lines contain 1 to 10 words; the first word should start with an upper case letter. The rest of the words can be mixed case. All the words in a line can contain characters such as ,-./

Positive Samples:
Example 1:

My favorite books are as follows:\nA great book\nThe Effective Book onscala.io\nTest Book\n

Matches:

My favorite books are as follows:\nA great book\nThe Effective Book onscala.io\nTest Book\n

Example 2:

My favorite books are as follows:\nA great book\nanother sentence\nAnother book\n

Matches: lines until first letter of each line is upper case.

My favorite books are as follows:\nA great book\n

Negative Sample:

My favorite books are as follows:\na great book\nanother sentence\n 

Doesn't match
I created the following regular expression, but it matches every line regardless of whether it starts with an uppercase.
(^[A-Z].*:)\n(^[A-Z].+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9,.\/ ]+){1,10})

If the above regex matched the expected lines, I would replace \n with a space and comma.

Where does your regex confine subsequent lines to 10 words or fewer?  Why do you have a 15 line limit on subsequent lines?  You did not mention that in your description.

I intended (^[A-Z].+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9,.\/ ]+){1,10}  to match a line starting with an upper case letter with 10 or fewer words. From your question, it looks like the regex is counting lines and not the words per line.

did you intend to have partial matching? I saw that @anubhava updated your question but didn't see anything that originally that specified that use case.

@Thatalent: I only made formatting changes to make it better readable.

Sorry @anubhava, you're right. I realized OP added the second use case in their edit and I had just missed it. My question gotcha answered though and thank you for the clear edit!

You may use this regex to get your matches:
^[A-Z][^:\n]*:\n(?:[A-Z][\w,./-]*(?:\h+[\w,./-]+){0,9}\n)+

RegEx Demo
RegEx Details:

^: Start new line
[A-Z]: Match an upper case letter
[^:\n]*: Match 0 or more characters that are not :
:\n: Match colon followed by a line break
(?:: Start non-capture group

[A-Z][\w,./-]*: Match first word that must start with an uppercase letter
(?:\h+[\w,./-]+){0,9}: Match 0 to 9 of other words sepaeated with 1+ whitespaces
\n: Match a line break


)+: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 1+ times


I think you can update the regex to avoid partial matches on strings that have a second line that is valid but the third line isn't.

I believe OP wants partial matches. Please see example 2 in the question

Thanks for clarification I think I missed that or just saw an outdated version of the question originally.

Thank you so much for the solution and the explanation! It's doing exactly what I wanted.

First off use this site to test things: https://regex101.com/
It will save you so much time.
This should get you want you want, although you'll need to make sure you're not using a multiline flag so that it doesn't match your negative case.
^([A-Z](.*\h?){0,9}\n?)+

You can replace .* with a more restricted pattern for a single line (excluding the first character) like this:
^(([A-Z])([\w:.,-]*\h?){0,9}\n?)+

What's important here is that you do need a starting match but you also need a n ending match to make sure you partially match your negative case. I added the \h to only match tabs and spaces but not newlines.
Here's a demo with it
The biggest issues with your regex are:

It wasn't matching anything without a multiline flag. If you use the website I linked you can see that the second start of string meta character does not work without the m flag. That's because it will only match the start of the entire string unless you tell it to match the start of each line (that's what the multiline aspect means)
.+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9,.\/ ]+) this is redundant and not actually serving you what you think. .+ is basically matching the entire line except the last word (based on the space) and then it matches [a-zA-Z0-9,.\/ ] the last word or symbol and then repeats for 15 lines.

Problem 2 isn't that bad because it does do what you want for the most part but what I provide should be lean enough that you build off of it you run into problems later. Again you're original regex could if you remove the second ^ but I imagine something might mess up because there's a lot of unnecessary things in it.

I updated your demo to use the samples from the question and it fails: https://regex101.com/r/UPR5nD/2

Yup, I've updated it. I seem to have missed OP's second use case or saw the question before it was added.

This was very helpful in identifying problems with my regex. Much appreciated your detailed response and the demo.

with /m flag, your new version incorrectly matches: Abc\nDef or Abc\nDef:, neither of which has a first line ending in colon

@jhnc I might be missing but why would anyone add the multiline flag? Just pointing out that I do note to not use the /m flag because it's not a good idea given that the OC wants a full document match (matching until it break) and not a multi-match within a document. I might be missing something tho since I did misunderstand the OC previously.

I forget why I wrote that but possibly because applying your new regex to the demo in my first comment misses the third match without /m (it also returns the first two matches as a single match but the spec is ambiguous)
